# Implementing thread timeout in executor service

Tags: java, multithreading

So right now I have a fairly basic Executor service that I use to break my program into threads, like so:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
          // The i is used elsewhere
}
```

I was wondering if there was a good way to detect / close "crashed" or "frozen" threads?   I took a look at the documentation but it doesn't really seem to fit in with how I'm using this at all...

Can someone help me with this?  Thanks

Comment: You could keep references to your submitted ThreadHandlers and check them periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`threadPool.submit` returns `Future<T>` Object. So using this future Object you can have handle on your task execution. 
By using `isCancelled() and isDone` method you can check task has been canceled or done. Even more `get()` is blocking call which throws exception on interpret or cancel or in executionexception.

```
List<Future<?>> list = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    Future<?> task=threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
          // The i is used elsewhere
    list.add(task);
}
for(Future future : list){
   try{
       future.get();
   }catch(CancellationException cx){
   ...
   }catch(ExecutionException ex){
   ...
   }catch(InterruptedException ix){
   ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you think that you can show me an example of the implementation of this?   I'm a little confused on how to use the Future <t> to accomplish this.   I think I know how to use isCancelled / isDone, but those won't detect if something has crashed / stopped for some reason.

Comment: Awesome solution, this is a great explanation of how to handle my problem.

Comment: @A_Elric how you solved the problems with frozen threads. get() blocks until the thread completed and frozen threads never return any result. So the script is waiting...

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). You execute tasks through its `submit` method, then have a separate thread wait for completions with the `poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method. Tasks terminated with an exception will return a `Future` which upon `get()` will throw an `ExecutionException`.

Using the timeout you can also detect when too much time has passed before any task returns; the usefulness of this behaviour however depends much on your setting.

Comment: I really like this answer as well, since it introduces me to ExecutorCompletionService which is a great way to handle this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is interrupt cancelled tasks.  You can schedule tasks to be cancelled with a ScheduledExecutorService

If your code doesn't honour interrupts, you need to fix it so that it does.  This is very hard to workaround programmatically in anything close to a reliable way.