# Why aren't my threads timing out when they fail?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, executorservice

So I asked a question a little while ago: [Over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302984/implementing-thread-timeout-in-executor-service) that asked the question "How can I make my threads get killed if they take too long"

I have implemented the solution mentioned there but under certain rare circumstances where a thread times out, the program can still fail / lock up (see: Keep the main() method open, and prevent further cron runs of the program).

Here's the source I'm using:

```
 //Iterate through the array to submit them into individual running threads.
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
    List<Future<?>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
        Future<?> task = threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(objectArray[i], i));
        taskList.add(task);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    //Event handler to kill any threads that are running for more than 30 seconds (most threads should only need .25 - 1 second to complete.
    for(Future future : taskList){
        try{
            future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(CancellationException cx){ System.err.println("Cancellation Exception: "); cx.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ExecutionException ex){ System.err.println("Execution Exception: ");ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InterruptedException ix){ System.err.println("Interrupted Exception: ");ix.printStackTrace();
        }catch(TimeoutException ex) {future.cancel(true);}
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

So my question is:  with this code implemented, why is the executor service not cutting things off at 30 seconds.

Comment: Note: your timeout increases for each task. e.g. if the first task takes 29 seconds, your second task has 59 seconds to complete.

Comment: Can you comment on how to fix this?  As that wasn't intended.

Comment: I have added an answer/solution to one of the causes of a longer timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I suspect your worker threads are still running.  You are calling `future.cancel(true);` but all that does is set the interrupt flag on the thread -- it does not actively interrupt your running code.  Another way to "interrupt" code is to set some `volatile boolean shutdown` flag to be true and to test for that in your code.  See here for [more details about interrupting threads](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/interrupting-java-threads/5144546).

You need to make sure that your `ThreadHandler` code handles interrupts correctly.  It needs to, for example, check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in loops or in other code blocks.  You also need to make sure that you are handling `InterruptedException` correctly and not just swallowing the interrupt.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12060317/179850) for more information about thread interrupts.

Comment: Hrm, that would be really difficult to handle with my current data structure.   The method that all these are passing to is extremely simple:  Essentially it does a object.run() so each object gets its own thread.  There is no loop running at all, if I do a loop I'd end up using each object many times which would cause a LOT of issues.

Comment: Inside of the `object.run()` methods, you are going to have to be able to detect if the thread is interrupted.  That means that you are going to have to test for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in your code.  What are these objects doing?

Comment: Well, each thread has it's own set of jobs to do, but they are pulling specific data from online sources to predict events... I can't say much more without breaking NDA.

Comment: No worries.  My point is that there is no easy way to stop the code _without_ the code checking for interrupt or for some shared variable.  See here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/interrupting-java-threads/5144546

Comment: So, my essential problem is that I'm thinking that there is an issue with http requests timing out.  The problem is that I'm using just a "basic" method of getting them:  

Example:  
    URL urlObject = new URL("http://myUrl");
            InputStream in = urlObject.openStream();

From there I just use outputstream and write to a file.   Assuming that the website I was connecting to sent over a syn/ack but didn't even finish sending the file due to network latency or some other issue, the program would hang.  I would have no "real" way to put in a thread.isinterrupted because it wouldn't go

Comment: past the point where it tried to read in the file.   This throws a kink into things that I can't think my way around.

Comment: Probably. I'd use apache's HttpClient where you can set the connection and IO timeouts.  Otherwise you are at the mercy of the server and the netwrok @Damien.Bell.

Comment: I use httpclient extensively in other parts of the program.  Embarassing sidenote:  I've never used it to save to a file...I suppose it wouldn't really be all that hard.

Answer (score 1):

You have an increasing amount of timeout for each task which may not be intended.  Instead you can shutdown the thread pool after you timeout and cancel the rest.

```
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
threadPool.shutdownNow(); // interrupt any running tasks.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole chapter dedicated Task Cancellation in the book Java Concurrency in Practice. From what I've read the task cancellation has to be in the finally block to make sure the task is always ended.

```
    try{
            future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
           // log error message and falls through to finally block
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            future.cancel(true); // interrupt task
        }
```

Interrupted status has to be restored while handling the InterruptedException.

```
           catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
```

In the ThreadHandler task check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() flag and throw an InterruptedException if true propagating the Interrupt status.